# rendering form in another view , form not showing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

I'm trying to render a form inside a modal. It is rendering it however the form_for doesn't show up only the input therefore I can't target the submit and I need it in order to do ajax.

Adgroup/views/edit.html.haml

```
%div(id="openModal" class="modalDialog")
    %div
        %a(href="#close" title="Close" class="close")
        = render "/cars/new"
```

Cars/views/new.html.haml

```
= form_for :car, :url => {:controller => 'cars', :action => 'create'}, :html => {:multipart => true,:id =>'car-form'} do |f|
%div(class="control-group")
    = label_tag             "Year"
    %br
    = text_field_tag    "year"
%br

%div(class="control-group")
    = label_tag             "make"
    %br
    %select{ :name => "make", :class => "chosen" }
        - @makes.each do |m|
            %option{:value => m.id}= "#{m.name}"
%br

%div(class="control-group")
    = label_tag             "Model"
    %br
    = text_field_tag    "model"
%br

%div(class="control-group")
    = label_tag             "Trim"
    %br
    = text_field_tag    "trim"
%br

%div(class="control-group")
    = label_tag             "Car Image(s)"
    %br
    = file_field_tag    "files[]"
%br


= submit_tag
```

It's a bit odd since I am rendering in a different view and it works.

cars/backend.html.haml

```
%div(class="backend-unit")
%h2 Add Cars
= render 'new'
```

And this is my javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#car-form').on('submit',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('hello');
});
```

});

Althoug never gets to the hello because it doesn't have the form_for and therefore i can't even target the submit.
Any idea why??

Answer (score 0):

Rails accepts `render` path relative to the `app/views` path and if you have foolder structures like `app/views/cars/views/new.html.haml` then you should use `= render "cars/views/new"`. And its a little confusing to answer since you have mentioned that you have `cars/backend.html.haml` , here there is no `views` after `/car` so not sure what your structure looks like.